# Is it possible to write an arara rule that invokes another arara rule?

Tags: arara

Is it possible to create an `arara` rule which possibly invokes other `arara` rules?

I've managed to write an `arara` rule which conditionally executes a command.

```
!config
# open rule for arara
# author: AEllett
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: open
name: PREVIEW
commands:
  - <arara>  @{isTrue ( isFile ("./.design/open.pdf.true"), 
                        "open ".concat(getBasename(file)).concat('".pdf"')
                        ""
                      )}
arguments: []
```

what I would like to do is write a similar rule which would conditionally invoke another `arara` rule.

Comment: What's your aim?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel arara already comes with a `pdflatex` directive.  I've written a rule for compiling via `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.  Generally, I compile with `pdflatex` so I sometimes forget that I need to use the other route when working with `pstricks`.  So I'd like to build an arara rule which checks for the existence of a file `.design/use.pstricks.true` and if present arara will call the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` rule, otherwise it will invoke the `pdflatex` directive.

Comment: This can be achieved inside the tex file with arara 4 which is only available via github: https://github.com/cereda/arara/wiki/Features-in-arara-4.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the current version of `arara` which is available via CTAN, it's quite difficult. However Paulo provides a [new `arara` version at GitHub](https://github.com/cereda/arara) which won't be uploaded to CTAN in a short time.

The new version has some nice gimmicks which are well explained in the [Wiki](https://github.com/cereda/arara/wiki/Features-in-arara-4.0).

If you are using `arara 4RC3` you can use the following header:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true } if missing ('use.pstricks.true')
% arara: pstricks if exists ('use.pstricks.true')
```

The rule `pstricks` could be:

```yaml
!config
# pstricks rule for arara
# author: Marco Daniel
# requires arara 4.0+
identifier: pstricks
name: LATEX-DVIPS-PS2PDF
commands: 
    - <arara> latex @{action} @{draft} @{shell} @{synctex} @{options} "@{file}"
    - <arara> dvips "@{getBasename(file)}.dvi" -o "@{getBasename(file)}.ps" @{dvipsoptions} 
    - <arara> ps2pdf @{ps2pdfoptions} "@{getBasename(file)}.ps" "@{output}.pdf"
arguments:
#arguments for convertion
- identifier: output
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.output}
  default: <arara> @{getBasename(file)}
- identifier: dvipsoptions
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: ps2pdfoptions
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
#arguments for latex
- identifier: action
  flag: <arara> --interaction=@{parameters.action}
- identifier: shell
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.shell,"--shell-escape","--no-shell-escape")}
- identifier: synctex
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.synctex,"--synctex=1","--synctex=0")}
- identifier: draft
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.draft,"--draftmode")}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
```